# PHPmyadmin , mySQL. how to select multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have problem to echo from two tables from the database. How to select two tables from database with has condition?

```
<?php session_start(); 
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $db=mysql_select_db("fyp2", $con);  
  $username=$_SESSION['username'];   
  $query="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username='$username'";
  $result=mysql_query($query);      
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
?>
```

In this situation, only one table can display, another table that i has insert it display no output.

Comment: Do you know SQL `JOIN` ? Seems it is what you are looking for

Comment: Also, you should share your code. Post your actual query

Comment: What is the other table, and what is their relationship?

Comment: how to create the SQL JOIN ?

Comment: the other table is service, i want to echo from two table, table 1 is customer and table 2 is service, from customer  and service need to display in same page.details from table customer is existing from after user has register.

Comment: there isn't a 2 table query here

Answer (score 0):

** Please implement that query **

```
<? include ("conn.php");
   $sql = "SELECT p.id,
                  p.name,
                  ps.name AS size_name
             FROM PRODUCT p
             JOIN PRODUCT_SIZES ps ON ps.size_id = p.size_id";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
  <td><? echo $row['id']; ?></td>
  <td><? echo $row['name']; ?></td>
  <td><? echo $row['size_name']; ?></td> 
</tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Queries' fine, but please never ever use MySQL_ again, either use PDO/MySQLi_, MySQL library is deprecated and a security risk especially on the internet we live on today...

Comment: Yes i know but its answer for how to develop query. you can try that query with PDO or MySQLi.